# Representation theory - how to show a subrepresentation is irreducible?

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, invariant-subspace

Consider the permutation group $S_3$ that permutes $\{1,2,3\}$. Let $V = \mathbb{C}^3$ be a vector space. We can have a representation of $S_3$ using $3\times 3$ matrices.

In the [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rDzaKASMTM&list=PL57457844458A5A1F) I am following, it is then shown that $V = V_1\oplus V_2$ where $V_1 = span\{(1,1,1)^T\}$ and $V_2 = span\{(a,b,c)^T \vert\  a+b+c = 0\}$. How can one show that these are irreducible subrepresentations? For $V_1$, it is one dimensional so it follows but for $V_2$, how can one see that there is no subspace that is invariant under $S_3$?

Is there a general technique to know that one has decomposed the representation into a direct sum of subrepresentations?

Comment: There is another way to show $V_2$ is irreducible: show every (nonzero) vector's orbit is a spanning set. Equivalently, find a particularly nice vector whose orbit is spanning, then show that vector is in the span of every other (nonzero) vector's orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't been introduced to characters yet, then here is a more direct approach for low dimensional problems.

*note:* I assume you are using the standard (injective) representation of $S_3$ with permutation matrices. (Otherwise e.g. you could have a trivial 3-d representation where every permutation is mapped to $I_3$.)

Note that $S_3$ is not an abelian group, thus its (injectively mapped) representation isn't either.  If $V_2$ is a direct sum of two 1-d subpaces (i.e. if $V_2$ is *reducible*), then all 6 of your permutation matrices are simultaenously diagonalizable
$\implies$ the representation is commutative $\implies S_3$ is abelian, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

In general (for an arbitrary group), $V_2$ may or may not be irreducible. Here, you can check $V_2$ is irreducible by computing its chatacter:

There are three conjugacy classes of $S_3$, represented by $1$, $(123)$, and $(12)$. The character of $V_2$ has value $2$, $-1$, and $0$ on these classes, respectively. The inner product of it with itself is
$$\frac{1}{6}(2^2 \times 1+(-1)^2 \times 2 + 0^2 \times 3) = 1$$
So it is irreducible.

Comment: I see - This was the first lecture in the series on representation theory so characters have not been introduced yet but this was an excercise. I will keep this in mind! Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. How is $V_2$ a representation of an arbitrary group?

Comment: @runway44 I mean for any group acting on some set you can define the permutation representation, and subtract away the trivial representation to get this "$V_2$".